# How can I restart ambari server for multiple node using single script file

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am using Hortonworks cluster , Many time we stop and start ambari server by using root and doing password less ssh to each server. Can we do it in single click I mean using script file or any other option to do same. (Something like just execute one script and that will do all process for you). I checked on google but not found any specific link for it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean "single click"? There is no UI for managing OS services built into HDP

Comment: single click means using some script (ex =  **./autoscript.sh start/stop/restart** Something like this)

Comment: Are you familiar with Ansible? And its service module? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html

Comment: No I am not familiar with Ansible.

Comment: Ok, well, then without something like that, then you would need a for loop in a shell script that launches an SSH session running your commands. There is no "built-in" tool to do this

Comment: Ok That will also be fine. As it reduce manual work.

Comment: Puppet Bolt is another option. https://puppet.com/products/puppet-bolt

Comment: This is very helpfull for me. Thanks a lot.